# Can we use "the other day" to express an event on a day that happened several months ago

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

According to the dictionary

> **[the other day/morning/evening/week...](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/day#other_idmg_3)**: ​recently
>
> I saw Jack the other day.
>
> I was in your area the other week.
>
> I woke up the other morning and just could not get myself out of bed.
>
> I was watching TV the other evening, when…

Say, I met a person 100 or 200 or even 300 days ago,

Is it still correct to say "**I met him the other day**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. *the other day* might reach back as far as two weeks or *possibly* (as we get older!) three.

100 days ago might be expressed as *a few weeks ago* (or *some weeks ago*), 200 as *a few months ago* and 300 as *a year or so ago*.

Comment: In ascending order of 'time ago', I would probably say yesterday, the other day, last week, the other week, etc, but the whole point, as Longman says, is that 'the other day/morning/week etc are used to say that something happened recently, _without saying exactly when_', so if we get too precise we lose the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

No. In this context, "the other day" means something more than one, but no more than ... well, it's not precise, but I'd say something like seven to fourteen. In other words, not yesterday but within the last week-ish. Definitely not 100+.

See also [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245457/when-is-an-event-so-old-that-the-phrase-the-other-day-no-longer-applies).

Comment: Your 'within the last week-ish' and 'something like seven to fourteen' contradict each other.  I would say earlier than yesterday counts as 'the other day'. Lexico says 'a few days ago' and Cambridge just says 'recently'. So I would be wary of giving precise limits.

Comment: I *was* being wary of giving my precise limits -- hence: ..."well, it's not precise", and "-ish", and "something like". As for being contradictory, that's the beauty/curse of natural language, especially English. As Whitman said, _"Do I contradict myself? Very well then I contradict myself, (I am large, I contain multitudes.)"_ :-)

Comment: +1 for Whitman :-)